# May $\Sigma_3$-collection hold below $\Sigma_3$-admissible ordinals for Gödel's L?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Suppose you have a system X=$KP$ + infinity plus $\Sigma_{3}$-collection and $\Delta_{2}$-specification. May $L_{\delta}\vDash X$ for some $\delta$ smaller than all $\Sigma_{3}$ admissible ordinals?